# PostgreSQL tsvector configuration: how to allow special characters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've set up a new text search configuration in PostgreSQL. This configuration uses an empty stop word file, DictFile and AffFile.

A simple test...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ts_debug('public.myconfig', 'C++ and C# and PHP');
```

...works (nearly) fine except the fact that the lexemes for 'C++' and 'C#' are both 'C'. Basically, all I would like to do is to make sure that the lexeme for 'C++' is 'C++' and that the lexeme for 'C#' is 'C#', hence enabling the user to query for 'C++'.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is two-fold.

1. The first issue is with indexing. The default config uses stemming to index the data and hence you get the lexeme 'C' for 'C++' and 'C#'. You can use the 'simple' config to index the data but then you will end up with unwanted words in the index. What I did was convert 'C++' to 'Cplusplus' and index that. Since 'Cplusplus' has no lexeme, it will be inxexed as is. You can do the same for 'C#' by making it 'CSharp' in the index data.
2. The second issue is with searching. Now that the indexed data is okay, we need to make sure that we convert the search terms for the special words. If the user types in 'C++", you need to convert it to 'Cplusplus' before performing the search.

I created a function on the DB that took in a string and converted all occurences of the special terms.

I have not used TSearch in a while, so I am not sure if TSearch allows you to setup and exception list the same way it allows for stopwords.